# Reading a csv in polars

Tags: python, python-polars

What is the difference between `polars.read_csv` vs `polars.read_csv_batched` vs `polars.scan_csv` ?

`polars.read_csv` looks equivalent to `pandas.read_csv` as they have the same name.

Which one to use in which scenario and how they are similar/different to `pandas.read_csv`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [`polars.read_csv_batched`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.read_csv_batched.html) is pretty equivalent to [`pandas.read_csv(iterator=True)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html).
- [`polars.scan_csv`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.scan_csv.html) doesn't do anything until you perform an operation on the dataframe like [`dask.dataframe.read_csv`](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/generated/dask.dataframe.read_csv.html) (lazy loading).

Scenarios:

- I use [`pandas.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) when my data is messy or complex in structure and the data is not too large
- I use [`polars.read_csv`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.read_csv.html) when my data file is very large (> 10GB).

*This is an answer based solely on my (humble) opinion.*

Comment: Thanks buddy, I will wait for other answers before I accept.

Comment: Take your time, I know very little about Polars compared to Pandas. What is important is what you do with your dataframe afterwards. Pandas has a lot of transform function but Polars is clearly faster.

Comment: Another point: in general when my files are very large, I convert them to parquet format to be able to reload them very quickly and above all to be able to load only the data that interests me with filters.

Comment: Great! I too am new to polars. Looks like it is very fast for large datasets.

Answer (score 3):

`polars.scan_csv` produces a query plan (called a `LazyFrame`). You can then build you query and on the end call `collect` to materialize a `DataFrame`.

This is the case for all `scan_` methods. The benefit of this is that the Polars optimizer then can push down optimizations into the readers. It can apply filters in the readers and only selects columns it needs. This can save a lot of work.

`polars.read_csv` can be seen as `polars.scan_csv().collect()`. E.g. you simply read all the data and immediately produce a `DataFrame`. This means that you might do work that was not needed. The Polars optimizer is not able to do anything if you want a result immediately.

I don't agree with the other answer that `polars.read_csv` only should be used when data is large. It is just as well suitable for smaller data.

Comment: Did I say that you should only use polars for large dataframes? No, I don't think so... I clearly indicated that this was my use case: "I use" and not "you should only use". Thanks to correct your last sentence.